# Redis is slow to get large strings

Tags: django, performance, caching, redis

I'm kind of a newb with Redis, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I'm using Django with Redis as a cache.

I'm pickling a collection of ~200 objects and storing it in Redis.

When I request the collection from Redis, Django Debug Toolbar is informing me that the request to Redis is taking ~3 **seconds**. I must be doing something horribly wrong.

- The server has 3.5GB of ram, and it looks like Redis is currently using only ~50mb, so I'm pretty sure it's not running out of memory.
- When I `get` the key using the redis-cli it takes just as long as when I do it from Django
- Running `strlen` on the key from redis-cli I'm informed that the length is ~20 million (Is this too large?)

What can I do to have Redis return the data faster? If this seems unusual, what might be some common pitfalls? I've seen [this page](http://redis.io/topics/latency) on latency problems, but nothing has really jumped out at me yet.

I'm not sure if it's a really bad idea to store a large amount of data in one key, or if there's just something wrong with my configuration. Any help or suggestions or things to read would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you don't have to store the whole objects/collections?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Redis is not designed to store very large objects. You are not supposed to store your entire collection in a single string in Redis, but rather use Redis list or set as a container for your objects.

Furthermore, the pickle format is not optimized for space ... you would need a more compact format. Protocol Buffers, MessagePack, or even plain JSON, are probably better for this. You should consider to apply a light compression algorithm before storing your data (like Snappy, LZO, Quicklz, LZF, etc ...).

Finally, the performance is probably network bound. On my machine, retrieving a 20 MB object from Redis takes 85 ms (not 3 seconds). Now, if I run the same test using a remote server, it takes 1.781 seconds, which is expected on this 100 Mbit/s network. The duration is fully dependent on the network bandwidth.

Last point: be sure to use a recent Redis version - a number of optimization have been done to deal with large objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely just the size of the string.  I'd look at whether your objects are being serialized efficiently.