# Redis timing out on long strings (below the 512 MB max)

Tags: ruby, redis

This is using the [Ruby client](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb).

```
> long_string = 'x' * 9_000_000; "created"
"created"
> long_string.bytesize / (1024.0 * 1024.0) # size in megabytes
8.58306884765625
> client.set('test', long_string)
Redis::TimeoutError: Connection timed out
```

I get the timeout error after five seconds (the default timeout). When I raise the timeout even to ten minutes, it still fails. Whether this happens also seems to be dependent on past calls to `client.set`, even at different keys.

According to the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/data-types), the max size for strings is 512 MB. Is this over-optimistic?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11861586/2339708) vaguely suggests that Redis is not meant to handle long strings. Is that what's going on, or is the issue in the Ruby library?

Comment: Is your Redis running on the same machine or on another server?

Comment: @spickermann: I have a local Redis instance for development and a Heroku Redis instance in production, and we see it on both. (although the local instance appears to be able to handle longer strings before going kaput).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Redis limitation, more likely a client setting. Repeating the example with a different client (Python's redis-py) does not reproduce the issue:

```
In [1]: long_string = "x" * 9000000

In [2]: len(long_string) / (1024.0 ** 2)
Out[2]: 8.58306884765625

In [3]: import redis

In [4]: r = redis.StrictRedis()

In [5]: r.set('test', long_string)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: longer = long_string * 50

In [7]: r.set('test2', longer)
Out[7]: True

In [8]: r.strlen('test2')
Out[8]: 450000000
```

Comment: Great, I'll make a bug report to them. Thanks!