# Fetching results from Celery backend is abnormally slow

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I'm using Celery with a Redis broker to do some "heavy" processing for my Django app. Everything is running locally in Docker containers on WSL2.

The tasks output a JSON which is roughly 2.5 Mb large and it takes up to 9 seconds to retrieve the result via `get()` in the Django app. For smaller payloads, the time goes down

I tried increasing the RAM and the CPU for WSL2 up to 6 CPUs and 8Gb RAM. Celery was configured with `--max-memory-per-child=1024000 --concurrency=4`

I've tried using different result_backend configuration with similar results:

- Redis
- RPC
- SQLite with SQLAlchemy

I tried setting an interval when using SQLite (doesn't matter for RPC & Redis) with a 0.5sec improvement `get(interval=0.01)`

I also tried changing the result_serializer from JSON to pickle for poorer performance. But I don't think the serializer is the culprit here as serializing / deserializing the same JSON is pretty fast in console

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: pickle.dumps(big_dict,0), number=10)
0.567067899999528

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: pickle.loads(str), number=10)
0.3542163999991317
```

I tried using compression, only zlib seemed to provide a small gain.

I'm not too familiar with this setup but IMHO I should be able to retrieve results faster. The best I could achieve was 6sec. Any idea how to improve this or how to explain it ?

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://{host}:{port}/{db}".format(
    host=os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST'),
    port=os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT'),
    db=os.environ.get('CELERY_REDIS_DB')
)
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://{host}:{port}/{db}".format(
    host=os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST'),
    port=os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT'),
    db=os.environ.get('CELERY_REDIS_DB')
)
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///celery.sqlite'  # SQL Example (need SQLAlchemy==1.4.29 in requirements.txt)
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://localhost'  # RPC Example
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Redis [has a reputation for being bad at dealing with large objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11861586/6043170) and is not generally intended to be a large object store.  You're better off using a general purpose RDBMS or a file store and returning a key to where the JSON can be retrieved.

Comment: You're right, the issue was bound to the objects size. Especially the input object which was ~9MB large (only noticed that later on). Sending and retrieving those large objects made me loose any benefit of using Celery with Redis compared to processing the task locally. Haven't tried to store the input in a RDBMS though